# Dynamically control the number of grids to appear based on screen width

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a grid layout displaying 3 grids in a row , now i have been trying is if the width of screen is above 1600 px i want the row to display 4 grid items, i am controlling the items using this bit of code

```
 <div class="item row" ng-repeat="row in Scroller |filter:$parent.searchText" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0">

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" ng-repeat="scrollIndex in [$parent.$index, $parent.$index + 1, $parent.$index + 2]" ng-init="scroll = Scroller[scrollIndex]">
```

now if i add $parent.$index + 3 that adds one more grid item to row,, but how to do it for above 1600 px width screen to display 4 grid items.

In controllers

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return window.innerWidth;
}, function (value) {
    return value;
});
$scope.gridDisplay = '';

if (value > 1600) {
    $scope.gridDisplay = [$parent.$index, $parent.$index + 1, $parent.$index + 2, $parent.$index + 3];
}
else {
    $scope.gridDisplay = [$parent.$index, $parent.$index + 1, $parent.$index + 2];
}
```

and i am calling gridDisplay in HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is 
 A hack i have made 2 view templates one for below 1600px and one for above 1600 px and used  a condition

if ($(window).width() < 1600)
        $scope.template = "app/views/x1.html"
    else
        $scope.template = "app/views/x2.html"